# Utilizar paradox con Visual Studio

Tags: c#, vb.net, base-de-datos, visual-studio

Buen dia,
tengo una base de datos creada en paradox, y debo realizar una pequeña aplicacion que muestre un reporte con los registros, esta debe ser windows en C# o VB, alguien que me recomiende algun tutorial de como utilizarlo.
o que me explique donde puedo abrir los archivos de la base de datos, si es que se pueden realizar querys, y como hacer las conexiones con VS.
Necesito informacion de donde partir y en internet n he encontrado mucho.
Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Podrias usar las librerias de OleDb para acceder a paradox, pero el problema no es este, sino conseguir el driver correcto.

Depende de la version de la db que estes utilizando, pero podrias intentar usando los connection string mencionados aqui:

[Paradox connection strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/paradox/)

en el codigo usarias ado.net serian las clases OleDbConnection, OleDbCommand, etc

Comment: Muchas gracias. Me es útil, sin embargo mi problema mas grande es como abrir esos archivos o que driver utilzar